# Cakephp Form Helper

Tags: php, cakephp, form-helpers

How can i achieve the following using **cakephp form helper**

```
<input type="text"  required>
```

Comment: You really shouldn't be using the required attribute for any sort of validation, look into the core CakePHP Validation, if you need it for javascript, set a class name.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
$this->Form->input('foo', array('required' => 'required'));
```

This will set the `required` attribute in longhand `required="required"` format, but will have the same effect.

Comment: I don't know why, but for me does not work. This work for me:
    $this->Form->input('foo', array('required' => TRUE));