# Is it possible to force the form helper to render a field as required even if it isn't in CakePHP?

Tags: forms, cakephp

Is there some parameter or workaround I can use to have the form helper render a field as if it were required by the model even if the model does not actually require it?

(I'm looking for the cakephp required rendering type, not the actual 'required' form property making this a different question than [Cakephp Form Helper](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5428814/cakephp-form-helper))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All the "required" style is is a specific CSS class you can set yourself:

```
$this->Form->input('foo', array('div' => array('class' => 'input text required')));
```