# cakephp - how to set presentation of view required username on login

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.1

I have a login view, like this:

```
<?php
echo $this->Form->create('User');
echo $this->Form->input('username',array('required' => true));
echo $this->Form->input('password');
echo $this->Form->end(__('Login'));
?>
```

The problem is password shows with a * and bolded as a required field, but the username doesnt, because there are some situations where the username is blank.

The docs say you can pass the required field in the array options but dont give an example of how to 
do this. I tried above and that didnt work. Any ideas?

[image]
thanks
Joel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Searching around](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7257639/is-it-possible-to-force-the-form-helper-to-render-a-field-as-required-even-if-it), this appears to be the solution.

```
$this->Form->input('username', array('div' => array('class' => 'input text required')));
```

And that does give you the same div classes any other required field has. When I tested it, however, the issue was that the label wasn't showing the bold-and-* look (which to me is the whole point), so add a tiny modification.

```
$this->Form->input('username', array('label'=>array('class'=>'required'),
                                     'div' => array('class' => 'input text required')));
```

And that should do the trick. Even just the label parameter will be enough *for the look*, but do add the div parameter in case any error needs to be displayed.